# Error in connecting to Spark using SparklyR

Tags: apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

I have a docker container in which I'm trying to connect to a spark cluster using sparklyR. Here is my code

```
library(sparklyr)
sc <- spark_connect(master = "yarn-client", app_name="your application name")
```

However it's not very stable, it works fine but sometimes it throws the following error

```
<simpleError in eval(external_call[[1]]): object 'value' not found>
```

and this is the application log on yarn

```
19/11/21 16:20:33 ERROR yarn.ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception:
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.s                       cala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:779)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:778)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:833)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to 3095098da5a8:40266
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
 Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 3095098da5a8
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:146)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:43)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:63)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:57)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:32)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:108)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:208)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:49)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:188)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:82)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:978)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:512)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:423)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:482)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    ... 1 more
19/11/21 16:20:33 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Final app status: FAILED, exitCode: 10, (reason: Uncaught exception: org.apache.spark.                       SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.s                       cala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:779)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:778)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:833)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to 3095098da5a8:40266
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)




Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 3095098da5a8
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:146)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:43)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:63)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:57)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:32)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:108)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:208)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:49)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:188)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:82)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:978)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:512)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:423)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:482)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    ... 1 more)
19/11/21 16:20:33 INFO yarn.ApplicationMaster: Unregistering ApplicationMaster with FAILED (diag message: Uncaught exception: org.apa                       che.spark.SparkException: Exception thrown in awaitResult:
    at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.awaitResult(RpcTimeout.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRefByURI(RpcEnv.scala:101)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv.setupEndpointRef(RpcEnv.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runExecutorLauncher(ApplicationMaster.scala:514)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.s                       cala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anonfun$run$1.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:245)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$3.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:779)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1692)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:778)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:244)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:803)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:833)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ExecutorLauncher.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Failed to connect to 3095098da5a8:40266
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:245)
    at org.apache.spark.network.client.TransportClientFactory.createClient(TransportClientFactory.java:187)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.createClient(NettyRpcEnv.scala:198)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:194)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.Outbox$$anon$1.call(Outbox.scala:190)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: 3095098da5a8
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName0(InetAddress.java:1281)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1193)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:1127)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getByName(InetAddress.java:1077)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:146)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils$8.run(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at io.netty.util.internal.SocketUtils.addressByName(SocketUtils.java:143)
    at io.netty.resolver.DefaultNameResolver.doResolve(DefaultNameResolver.java:43)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:63)
    at io.netty.resolver.SimpleNameResolver.resolve(SimpleNameResolver.java:55)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:57)
    at io.netty.resolver.InetSocketAddressResolver.doResolve(InetSocketAddressResolver.java:32)
    at io.netty.resolver.AbstractAddressResolver.resolve(AbstractAddressResolver.java:108)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:208)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:49)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:188)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:507)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:481)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:420)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:104)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:82)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:978)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:512)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:423)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:482)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:463)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultThreadFactory$DefaultRunnableDecorator.run(DefaultThreadFactory.java:138)
    ... 1 more
```

What's the issue?

Comment: See here: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-kubernetes.html#client-mode-networking